# Angular 4 - Error when displaying json data as a table

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Using Angular 4, Typescript I am unable to display content of below json:

1. timed_out, max_score in a text box
2. CV/JOB in a table.

   Any hints

   > {   "took": 56,   "timed_out": false,   "_shards": {
   >       "total": 18,
   >       "successful": 18,
   >       "failed": 0   },   "hits": {
   >       "total": 23381243,
   >       "max_score": 2.2639267,
   >       "hits": [
   >         {
   >           "_index": "2018-09",
   >           "_type": "ABC",
   >           "_id": "122",
   >           "_score": 2.2639267,
   >           "fields": {
   >             "CV": [
   >               "proc"
   >             ],
   >             "JOB": [
   >               "pap"
   >             ]
   >           }
   >         },
   >         {
   >           "_index": "2018-09",
   >           "_type": "ABC",
   >           "_id": "123",
   >           "_score": 2.2639267,
   >           "fields": {
   >             "CV": [
   >               "foo"
   >             ],
   >             "JOB": [
   >               "bnn"
   >             ]
   >           }
   >         }
   >       ]   } }

Comment: what is the error? what do you want to display? post your code

Comment: I want to display CV/JOB data as columns in a table

Comment: How you are displaying. Can you show some codes and how you are fetching data.

Comment: not sure. i am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nested **`ngFor`** in your case,

```
 <tr *ngFor="let dataobj of data.hits.hits">
   <td  *ngFor="let jobObj of dataobj.fields.JOB">               
      {{jobObj}}      
   </td >
   <td  *ngFor="let hitobj of dataobj.fields.CV">               
     {{hitobj}}      
    </td >            
</tr>
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itivac?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: thanks a lot @sajeetharan,  for the wonderful response.                          
               how do i display  timed_out, max_score in a text boxes?

Comment: just access the properties using dot operator {{data.timedout}} and {{data.hits.max_score}} , mark if the answer helped